# Adding a list inside a list from a linq to sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

Hello I am trying to add carriers to my friendmodel but i am unsure how to do so.

Here is my model:

```
public class FriendModel
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        [Display(Name = "Phone Name")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public List<CarriersModel> Carriers { get; set; }  

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int? SelectedCarrier { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my code:

```
var query = from f in db.Friends
                join uf in db.Users_Friends on f.Id equals uf.FriendId
                join c in db.Carriers on f.CarrierId equals c.Id
                select new {Friends = f, Users_Friends = uf, Carrier = c};

            var friends = new List<FriendModel>();

            foreach (var row in query)
            {
                friends.AddRange(query.Select(friend => new FriendModel()
                {
                    Id = friend.Friends.Id,
                    FirstName = friend.Friends.FirstName,
                    LastName = friend.Friends.LastName,
                    PhoneNumber = friend.Friends.PhoneNumber,
                    UserId = friend.Friends.Id,
                    Carriers = new List<CarriersModel>()
                    {
                        CarrierName = friend.Carrier.CarrierName,
                        CarrierEmail = friend.Carrier.CarrierEmail,
                    }
                }
                ));
            }
```

When I try to add the carriers like I do in the above code it errors. (Cannot resolve symbol). Is this not the way to do this?

Comment: How many db.Carriers are there supposed to be per db.Friends? Your model suggests there could be multiple carriers, but your query is only selecting one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
                Carriers = new List<CarriersModel>()
                {
                    CarrierName = friend.Carrier.CarrierName,
                    CarrierEmail = friend.Carrier.CarrierEmail,
                }
```

Try

```
                Carriers = new List<CarriersModel>()
                {
                  new CarriersModel(){
                    CarrierName = friend.Carrier.CarrierName,
                    CarrierEmail = friend.Carrier.CarrierEmail,
                  },
                }
```

update:
Maybe change your foreach loop to make some more sense

```
        foreach (var row in query)
        {
            friends.Add(new FriendModel()
            {
                Id = row.Friends.Id,
                FirstName = row.Friends.FirstName,
                LastName = row.Friends.LastName,
                PhoneNumber = row.Friends.PhoneNumber,
                UserId = row.Friends.Id,
                Carriers = new List<CarriersModel>()
                {
                    new CarriersModel(){
                        CarrierName = row.Carrier.CarrierName,
                        CarrierEmail = row.Carrier.CarrierEmail,
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Tried that it doesn't show any errors but throws an exception  Cannot create a query result of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PandaBrew.Models.CarriersModel]'.

Comment: ah btw why are you not using the `row` from your iterator? *.* This doesn't make sense at all to me

Comment: +1 The updated answer should work because the foreach is forcing the enumeration and stopping it from being a SQL Query

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can make a list. Try having an IEnumerable instead, and use this:

```
... snip ...
UserId = friend.Friends.Id,
Carriers = friend.Carrier.Select(c => new CarriersModel
    {
        CarrierName = c.CarrierName,
        CarrierEmail = c.CarrierEmail,
    })
etc
```

and in your model, you should have

```
public IEnumerable<CarriersModel> Carriers { get; set; }
```

---

As an aside, you don't need to do the `foreach (var row in query)` - the select will iterate all rows. You could have:

```
var friends = query.Select(<insert select here>)
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: adding that second select gives me cannot resolve symbol select. the select is part is invalid.

Comment: What type is friend.Carrier?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familier with Linq to SQL, but this should work:

```
      List<FriendModel> friendModels = (from f in db.Friends
                join uf in db.Users_Friends on f.Id equals uf.FriendId
                join c in db.Carriers on f.CarrierId equals c.Id
                select new FriendModel()
                {
                    Id = f.Id
                    FirstName = f.FirstName,
                    LastName = f.LastName,
                    PhoneNumber = f.PhoneNumber,
                    UserId = f.Id,
                    Carriers = c.Select(i=> new CarriersModel() { CarrierName = i.Name,  CarrierEmail = i.CarrierEmail })
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: ToList() wont work in a query, for the same reason he can't create a new List inside the query

Comment: His collection initialization is not correct. He is initializing a collection, and then setting properties for collection objects without instantiating them. He is not creating a valid list.

Comment: You are correct in that he has not got collection initialization syntax correct, however your code (as far as I know) will not work because you cannot call ToList() inside of a query. (You can do what you have suggested in LinqToObjects, because that isn't a query)

Comment: @berkeleybross: Thanks for the clarification. I guess it would be best to deal with the IEnumerable<T> then.